# Error while trying to install any npm packages

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I get this error while trying to install any package.

```
(node:13133) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

npm version

```
npm -v
9.7.2
```

node version

```
node -v
v20.4.0
```

I expect the packages to be installed properly

Comment: Already solved, i had to change my node to lts version

Comment: Please close your question.

Comment: Did you use nvm or any kind of Node manager? I have version 20.5.0 and npm version 9.8.0 after following the Node installation instructions for Ubuntu, and I get the same issue.